# How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to  evaluate $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$

I am clueless, I doubt if this  has a closed form  either.

Comment: the searched result should be $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805893/a-logarithmic-integral-int1-0-frac-log-left-frac1x1-x-rightx-sqrt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sub $u=(1+x)/(1-x)$; the resulting integral is

$$\int_1^{\infty} du \frac{\log{u}}{(u-1) \sqrt{u}} = 4 \int_1^{\infty} dv \frac{\log{v}}{v^2-1} = 2 \int_0^{\infty} dv \frac{\log{v}}{v^2-1}$$

The latter integral is easily attacked using contour integration methods, as done in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989504/prove-that-int-0-infty-frac-ln-xxn-1-dx-left-frac-pin-sin-left/989554#989554).  The result is $\pi^2/2$.  Alternatively, you may express the integral over the interval $[0,1]$, Taylor expand the denominator, and obtain a familiar sum.